# asp.net core Cookie policy option override for a specific cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

*My Startup.cs file has following configuration*

```cs
services.Configure(options => 
{
    //options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Utils.GetSameSiteMode(sameSiteModeConfigVal);
    options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
});
```

Now I am trying to create another cookie where i want to set **HttpOnly=false** so that i can tread it using `javascript` code

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("CookieName", cookieValue,new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = false,
            Secure = false
        });
```

> When I cheek in the browser , I see the `HttpOnly` is set to true

Is there any way to set **HttpOnly=false** for this particular cookie leaving other cookies as is?

Comment: Could you please tell me which asp.net core version you have used now? 2.2 or 3.1? Could you please tell me when you will call  ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append  method inside a MVC controller?Besides, I found you don't specify the CookiePolicyOptions for the Configure method? It seems this codes will not work.

Comment: I am using asp.net core 2.2 . I am calling Cookies.Append method in a controller action method once I am done generating a pdf file , this will help my front end code and it will know the file generation completed so it will stop showing the wait icon to user and download the file. Cookie policy option is specified and there are other Session and Authentication cookie whose HttpOnly property is true , I just want this particular cookie that I am creating after PDF file creation to have HttpOnly=false so that I can read this cookie through my JavaScript code.

Comment: @Debanjan Did you try setting options.HttpOnly to "HttpOnlyPolicy.None"? Perhaps the "Always" option is forcing HttpOnly to always be enabled (hence the name), even when you try to override it.

Answer (score 0):

By default `HttpOnlyPolicy.Always` policy overrides all cookie settings in application.

You can change your `OnAppendCookie` policy callback to whitelist cookie names you need:

```
options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => 
{
    if(cookieContext.CookieName.Equals("MyKnownCookieName"))
        cookieContext.CookieOptions.HttpOnly = false;

    CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
}
```

If you do not know cookie names in advance, you need some other way to notify the policy that your cookie should be `HttpOnly` anyway (I would personally use some common prefix).